# Shrunk application window sizes compared to resolution

Tags: display

Hi my screen display has suddenly gone a little weird. The launcher and the applications window/font sizes have shrunk as compared to the screen size. How do I restore normal configuration?

Answer (score 0):

You can access settings by typing `System Settings` in the Dash, or clicking "power" or "power cog" button in the top-right corner of the screen and choosing `System Settings`.

Once you entered on the `System Settings`, click on `Displays` and Then adjust the `Scale for menu and title bars` to a higher value.

[image: Screenshot of Displays]